# font eroded with firefox and chrome

Tags: css, fonts, cross-browser

I've got a problem with a non-system fonts in firefox and chrome on windows.
This font is Corbel. With Safari and Explorer on windows is ok, and with firefox and Safari on Mac is ok too, but with firefox and Chrome on windows the font is eroded and distorted. I don't know why...i try to set font-weight and font-style to normal, but nothing change!
The font is insert with font-face css. Here te code of css..

```
#menuWrapper ul li a {
font-family: 'Corbel';
color:#838484;
font-size:10px;
line-height:10px;
text-decoration:none;
}
```

thx!!!

Comment: Can we see a link to an exmaple?

Comment: I'm sorry, until the website is online i can't public anything..

Comment: You could post an example somewhere without compromising the anonymity of the site you're working on.

Comment: Also, is it just Corbel, or do other web fonts have the same problem?

Comment: just Corbel, on the website are other non-system fonts and they works good! maybe font problem?!

Comment: i add a print screen of my navigation: http://imageshack.us/f/707/senzatitolo1tp.png/

Answer (score 1):

You're probably going to want to use the `@font-face` property of CSS3.

```
@font-face 
{ 
    font-family: Corbel; src: url('Corbel.otf'/*whatever ext*/); 
} 

myElement
{ 
    font-family: Corbel, sans-serif; 
}
```

Using this will make sure that your custom font is loaded from your domain and able to be called. Make sure the paths to the font are correct also.

:)

Comment: yes i just use this, but the font is eroded, and i dont know why. I've got other non-system fonts on my website but they works perfectly...only this one has problem!! Maybe the font is corrupted or something else?

Comment: CAn you poist some screenshots of what's happening?

Comment: Try re-installing the font on the windows machine. I had this problem once with Georgia, it got repalced by something truly ugly.

Comment: yeah!!! i try to use font-squirrel generator with another Corbel font and now it works great!! thx Kyle!!

Answer (score 0):

Try copying the font file separately and using it with `@font-face`
Here is  a [tutorial](http://return-true.com/2010/05/css-3-custom-fonts-using-font-face/) to do that.

Comment: i just use font-face, here the code:

@font-face {font-family: 'Corbel';src: url('Corbel.eot');src: local('☺'), url('Corbel.woff') format('woff'), url('Corbel.ttf') format('truetype'), url('Corbel.svg') format('svg');font-weight: normal;font-style: normal;}

Comment: You could check in Firebug to see which one of the Corbel.* files is being loaded. Compare that to a browser where it looks okay.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a Windows machine set up to test it on, but you can try

```
text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
```

It has no effect on Mac machines because Mac has inherent text rendering.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/text-rendering